# Write a function that takes two natural numbers  and  as inputs and returns the set of all tuples of size  that sum to 

Tags: python, combinatorics

In python 3 I am trying to write a function that takes two natural numbers    and    as inputs and returns the set of all tuples of size    that sum to  .

I have built the following functions:

```
def get_tuples(length, total):
    if length == 1:
        yield (total,)
        return


    for i in range(total + 1):
        for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
            yield (i,) + t
```

which with, e.g.,  list(get_tuples(2, 8)) returns the correct results, and:

```
 def get_tuples(length, total):
    if length == 1:
        return [(total,)]

    comp = []
    for i in range(total + 1):
        for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
            comp.append((i,) + t)
        return comp
```

which however returns a wrong result (i.e. a single tuple). 
Can anybody please explain why, and how to fix the second function?

Comment: And the tuples contain positive integers right?

Comment: You have a `return` in loop, so it's exit during first pass.

Comment: @Tupteq thank you, and how can I make the second function work without a generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply place the return one indent out:

```
def get_tuples(length, total):
    if length == 1:
        return [(total,)]

    comp = []
    for i in range(total + 1):
        for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
            comp.append((i,) + t)
    return comp
```

Edit: Make sure you understand why

Comment: Hey I read it but I don't understand why the inner for loop with the recursive call to get_tuples(), could you explain that?

Answer (score 3):

owninggreendragsdude's answer is the right one, because it shows exactly the one thing you need to change in your code to make it work.

However, if you were wondering how to get rid of the recursion and make the code faster at the same time, here's a solution:

```py
def get_tuples_optimized(length, total):
    comp = []

    # Stack of partial tuples to process, initialized with an empty tuple
    todo = [(total, tuple())]

    # Loop as long as we have partial tuples on our stack
    while todo:
        # Take the next partial tuple
        amount_left, partial_tuple = todo.pop()

        if len(partial_tuple) == length - 1:
            # Put all that is left as the last element
            comp.append(partial_tuple + (amount_left,))
        else:
            # Add all possible extensions-by-one to our stack
            for i in range(amount_left + 1):
                extended_tuple = partial_tuple + (i,)
                todo.append((amount_left - i, extended_tuple))

    return comp
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
def get_tuples(length, total):
if length == 1:
    return [(total,)]

comp = []

for i in range(total + 1):
    for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
        comp.append((i,) + t)
return comp
```

Take the return statement out of the loop.